# Vue JS Radio button toggle all scenario

Tags: javascript, vue.js, radio-button

So I know how I can toggle all radio buttons in a group but I have a slightly niche case here. I'll try and explain as best I can here with code and comments.

**SomeComponent.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- This checkbox will toggle the selected stated of all radios -->
        <input class="toggleAll" type="checkbox" :checked="checked" @change="toggleAll">

        <!-- These will either toggle their own checked state or
        IF the above checkbox has been checked and all checkbox are selected, it would remove the 
        checked state from that one
        as not all the radios ARE selected anymore -->
        <input :checked="checked" class="radio" type="checkbox">
        <input :checked="checked" class="radio" type="checkbox">
        <input :checked="checked" class="radio" type="checkbox">
         <input :checked="checked" class="radio" type="checkbox">
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        name: 'SomeComponent',
        data() {
            return {
                checked: false,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            toggleAll() {
                this.checked = !this.checked;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

So basically, the input with the class of **toggleAll** will check/uncheck all checkboxes. However, checking any of the others should uncheck the one you clicked **plus** the toggleAll checkbox, as not all are checked anymore.

I can't seem to get this to work! I basically need to say look for the input with the class of toggleAll and change the data "checked" to **false** but I don't know how to do it.

TIA

Comment: You can't rely on a single boolean to drive the state of every checkbox.  Each checkbox will have to have it's own data element, or at least its own model variable.  Then its as simple as checking when one is changed, if it is unchecked, to uncheck the select all one.

Comment: OK so how can I can check the data of the child component has changed?

Comment: If you're working in Vue, why don't you use the `v-radio` component instead of the standard `input`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have any specific preference for the `checked` states, I would recommend using a list of boolean and toggle their respective states (with [`Vue.set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set) to overcome the [array change detection caveat](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)).

The example below uses a [computed setter/getter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) to reactively tell if all checkboxes are checked, and toggle them at once when the setter gets called.

By the way, I added an extra attribute ([`indeterminate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#Indeterminate_state_checkboxes)) that you might find useful.

I'm using the [`.prop`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) modifier on the "allChecked" checkbox to tell Vue that we want to bind this `indeterminate` as a DOM property instead of component attribute.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      checkList: [false, false, false, false]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    allChecked: {
      get() {
        return this.checkList.every(Boolean);
      },
      set(isChecked) {
        for (let index = 0; index < this.checkList.length; index++) {
          this.$set(this.checkList, index, isChecked);
        }
      }
    },
    indeterminate() {
      return !this.allChecked && this.checkList.some(Boolean);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app > input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11"></script>

<div id="app">
  <label>
  <input 
    v-model="allChecked"
    :indeterminate.prop="indeterminate"
    class="toggleAll" 
    type="checkbox" />
  Check all
  </label>

  <input 
    v-model="checkList[index]" 
    v-for="(checked, index) of checkList" :key="index"  
    class="radio" 
    type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer worked perfectly with some tweaking!

Answer (score -2):

It could be that your problem comes from the fact that the `@change` event only fires when a user interacts with the radio and changes. On the other hand, looking at your code, are you trying to change the main button's status using the `checkAll` method? In that case, what's the `toggleAll` referencing in `@change="toggleAll"`?

In any case, this should do it:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input class="toggleAll" type="checkbox" :checked="checked2" @change="toggleAll">

        <input :checked="checked" @change="toggleMain" class="radio" type="checkbox">
        <input :checked="checked" @change="toggleMain" class="radio" type="checkbox">
        <input :checked="checked" @change="toggleMain" class="radio" type="checkbox">
         <input :checked="checked" @change="toggleMain" class="radio" type="checkbox">
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        name: 'SomeComponent',
        data() {
            return {
                checked: false,
                checked2: false
            {
        },
        methods: {
            toggleMain() {
                this.checked2 = false;
            }
            ...
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a finite number of radios. There could be more or less than what are there now depending on what data I get back from the API.